# Is it possible to get the name of the function being compiled in GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc

Sorry, but I don't even know how exactly to ask this.

I want to generate a trace log with some of the methods or functions being run, but I don't want to write the command name in every method (I'm really lazy!).

Example:

My current code:

```
void doSomething() {
    TRACE("doSomething");
    // now do something!
    system("pause");
}
```

What I want to do:

```
void doSomething() {
    TRACE;
    // do something!
    system("pause");
}
```

Output expected (of both programs):

```
doSomething
Press any key to continue...
```

If you need me to be more clear, please let me know. I'll try to be as clear as possible.

Comment: I think you want `__func__`.  There's an explanation and examples at the bottom of [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function).  If TRACE is a macro, then it can substitute text including `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and/or `__func__` for use in the log.

Comment: @TonyD Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted! Please, post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira: Also, because you're using g++, you might look into [`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) as well.

Comment: You might want to look into the `-finstrument-functions` command line flag to insert the tracing code automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with something like this:

```
#define TRACE(message) TRACE_IMPL(__FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, message)

void TRACE_IMPL(const char *file, int line, const char *function, const char *message) {
    ...
}

int main() {
    TRACE("help");
}
```

My next step, would be to change message to be a format string, and enable `printf()` style va_args on the Trace. Which would look something like:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define TRACE(format, ...) TRACE_IMPL("File: %s Line: %d Function: %s Message: " format "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__)

void TRACE_IMPL(const char *format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    vprintf(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main() {
    TRACE("help");
    TRACE("Canary %d", 2);
}
```

Which would output:

```
[8:18pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] ./foo
File: foo.c Line: 14 Function: int main() Message: help
File: foo.c Line: 15 Function: int main() Message: Canary 2
```

You could also use C++ streams if you wanted:

```
#include <iostream>

#define TRACE LogImpl(__FILE__, __LINE__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__)

class LogImpl {
    public:
        LogImpl(const char *file, int line, char *function) {
            std::cout << "File: " << file << " Line: " << line << " Function: " << function << " Message: ";
        }

        ~LogImpl() {
            std::cout << "\n";
        }

        LogImpl(LogImpl const &) = delete;
        LogImpl & operator=(LogImpl const &) = delete;

        template <typename T>
        LogImpl & operator<<(T const & obj) {
            std::cout << obj;
            return *this;
        }
};

int main() {
    TRACE << "help";
    TRACE << "Canary " << 2;
}
```

Comment: `printf`?  Much safer and more extensible to accept arguments to stream to an `iostream`.

Comment: @TonyD: That's fair. But then I'd probably toss this whole style, and just go with a Log object of some sort. If you'd like to write something like that up, I imagine that  Vinícius would find it interesting.

Comment: A log object alone can't help capture the function name (nor file, line...), so this "style" is necessary.  I've marked this as a duplicate so can't add another answer now!  Idea's very simple anyway: `#define TRACE(MSG) do { log_stream << __func__ << ' ' << MSG << '\n'; } while (false)` or similar.  `do`/`while (false)` is just there in case you want to later add to the compound statement (e.g. prefix `if (logging_enabled)`); it prevents breaking `if`/`else` clauses in the context of macro use - a common trick for macros.

Comment: @TonyD: Right, but then your formatting has become more complex, or you use an odd syntax of `TRACE("canary " << 2);` or `TRACE(boost::format("canary %1%") % 2);`

Comment: " or you use an odd syntax " - it's only odd until you get used to it ;-).

Comment: @TonyD: I've added to the post the syntax I'd probably use if I wanted an iostreams interface.

Comment: it's less flexible.  What will you do if you want to add a check for a "logging enabled" flag?  Check it in the constructor and on every call to `<<`?  Note that to call `<<` - potentially just to throw the value away - the arguments first need to be evaluated and that can be slow - not desirable when logging's disabled; with my approach from a few comments up you don't have to evaluate any arguments in that scenerio.

Comment: Wow, this scalated quickly! The implementation I've been using is with `iostreams`. Not as fancy as the one your provided but worked very well so far.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira true - worked on enough corporate libraries making these decisions to know all the pros and cons aren't immediately obvious... sometimes the design decisions limit what you can do later without rewriting "client" code, so choose well if it's a big system you're implementing and/or code outside your own control will adopt your interface.  Cheers